# How to migrate from Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime to Azure.Core?

Tags: c#, nuget

My project uses `Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime` but in [latest version 2.3.24](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime#versions-body-tab), it's mentioned that:

> This package has been deprecated.
>
> Please note, a newer package is available Azure.Core, you can find
> more information of this new package from
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/core-readme?view=azure-dotnet.

But I'm still unable to understand which Class, Interface etc. from `Azure.Core` can replace the Class, Interface of `Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime`.

For example,
I have a function for tracing, which uses `ServiceClientTracing` from `Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime` package:

```
bool _traced = ServiceClientTracing.IsEnabled;
string _id = null;
if (_traced)
{
    _id = ServiceClientTracing.NextInvocationId.ToString();
    Dictionary<string, object> _params = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    _params.Add("someKey", someKey);
    _params.Add("someToken", someToken);
    ServiceClientTracing.Enter(_id, this, "AddPowerBIEncryptionKey", _params);
}
...
```

Now, which class from `Azure.Core` can be used in this case?
Is there any documentation that I can follow to migrate? Or do I need to change my method according to the available classes in `Azure.Core`?

Comment: Refer to this GitHub issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/41005